# Android - Uniform size of AlertDialog buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-button

I'm trying to get my buttons in the AlertDialog even. Currently, the text for one button goes onto the second line and makes that button slightly larger than the other two. Here's my dialog (not in a fragment, just within the activity)

```
public void imageActions(final View v, final int position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Image Actions");
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.image_icon);
    alert.setNeutralButton("View Image", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              seeImage(v,position);
        } });   
    alert.setPositiveButton("Remove Image", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              sureToDelte(v,position);
        } });       
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
        } }); 
    alert.show();           
}
```

I tried adding this code after the `alert.show();` but it caused a crash.

```
Button positive = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
positive.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10));
Button negative = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button2);
negative.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10));
Button neutral = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button3);
neutral.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to edit your XML file, you can do something like this :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonID1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your Button" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonID2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Otherwise, if you really want to edit it programatically, use the LinearLayout proprieties like :

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_linear);
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams(); // Params
params.width = params.FILL_PARENT; // Fill the space horizontally
params.height = params.WRAP_CONTENT; // Fill the space vertically but "automatically", depends on the object's size.
```

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding what to do with these or where to put them. I don't have an XML file that I'm using with the AlertDialog, and when I created one all of the buttons are just saying "False". When I try it programatically, I'm still just getting a crash. How can I reference the buttons specifically to apply the LayoutParams to them?